# SSRS 2016 : HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs, errors, ssrs-2016

We have SSRS 2016 on Windows Server 2016.

Reporting Server configured with virtual directories

1. http://ServerName:80/Reports
2. http://ServerName:80/ReportServer

While I'm trying to connect to reports via there URLs I get the following error messages:

- For the first URL, I get the one below:

  > This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you
  >   are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from
  >   displaying.
- And this for the second URL:

  > HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

**Possible solutions I tried to fix these issues**

1. Installed latest update for SQL Server 2016.
2. Tried with different virtual directories 000 Deleted "Encrypted Content" and restarted SSRS service.
3. Changed SSRS service account to domain account
4. validated `rsreportserver.config`

   `<Add Key="SecureConnectionLevel" Value="0"/>`

   `<UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>`  -------Tried putting server name / IP instead of + sign

   `<IsWebServiceEnabled>True</IsWebServiceEnabled>`
5. Validate the login connecting to the database is member of`RSExecRole` in master, msdb ReportServer & ReportServerTempDB databases.

Please suggest what I'm missing to fix the error.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to access the URLs on the server or from a remote computer? When you attempt to access them is any error generated on SQL Server or Windows logs?

Comment: @Ronaldo I mentioned the error in my port. I think local server has every right to connect report server.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the errors in the post were shown on browser and a more detailed error could be found on `SQL Server logs` or Windows `event viewer`. Are SSRS and SQL Server instance on the same box?

Comment: @Ronaldo Yes, bothe services are on same box.